# Next Js error : POST "http://localhost:3000/register not found. My backend is running on port : 5000 , i have also added proxy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

```
    const postData = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { fullName , email , password } = user;

        const res = await fetch("/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                fullName,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })

        const data = res.json();
```

}

i m creating a signup page..using mongodb , nextjs ,nodejs / expressjs.

frontend is running on port 3000
backend is running on port 5000

i have also tried adding proxy in package.json ...but still not working

Comment: are you able to test the api with a tool like postman ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.